# Ajax Request to ApiView endpoint raises forbidden http error

Tags: django, ajax, django-rest-framework

I have been trying to to an AJAX Request to an ApiView endpoint.

```js
        $.ajax({
            url: '{% url 'edit_custom_user_additional_info' %}',
            method: "patch",
            data: $form.serialize(),
            header: {
                "X-CSRFToken": "{{ csrf_token }}"
            },
            success: function (data) {
                alert("Dati aggiuntivi salvati con successo");
            },
            error: function (data) {
                console.log("Errore durante il salvataggio dei dati aggiuntivi");
            },
        });
```

I have also added the `{% csrf_token %}` to the form but I still get Forbidden error.
I have also tried to add the CSRF Exempt but still the error.

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added this to the ajax request and it worked

```
beforeSend: function(xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", "{{ csrf_token }}");
}
```

Comment: If you have already resolved your question then please close the question